# Determine ker($f$), as well as a basis and the dimension of im($f$) of linear mapping $f : \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}[t]$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

First and foremost, apologies for my lack of "math-abilities".
Here we're given a linear mapping  $f : \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}[t]$ through the linear continuation of
$$
f(e_1) = 2t^2 - t + 1, \quad f(e_2) = t^3 - 2t, \quad f(e_3) = t^3 - 4t^2 - 2.
$$

How can I find the kernel of f, and/or the basis of the image of f? I'm new to the concept and couldn't find any helpful stuff on the internet (at least with polynomials).

Comment: Do you understand what $\mathbb{R}[t]$ is as a vector space? Can you give a basis?

Comment: I'd assume $\{1,t,t^2,...,t^n\}$?

Comment: Could I rewrite $f(e_1),f(e_2),f(e_3)$ into matrix form or is that "illegal"?

Comment: Correct, assuming that you wanted to write dots after $t^n$ too: $\mathbb{R}[t]$ is an infinite dimensional vector space (of countable dimension).

Comment: And yes, it is a good idea to rewrite $f$ in matrix form, if that helps you thinking about the problem.

Comment: I also would recommend you figure out if you maybe actually just hit a subspace, and which one (given the structures of the two spaces, one finite dimensional, one countable dimensional) you should be able to immediately see a subspace of $\mathbb{R}[t]$ you can factor over. And for that one you can then use the usual matrix dances (short hint, you got already a canonical basis on $\mathbb{R}[t]$ and can read of which of them even have a chance to be hit)

Comment: Would $$f := \left[ \begin{array}{cccc}
1 & -1 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & -2 & 0 & 3 \\
-2 & 0 & -4 & 1
\end{array} \right]$$ be a correct way of rewriting it?

Comment: Almost, but not quite. First, there is a "direction" problem: people usually write matrices so that the images of the basis vectors of the source are read vertically. Second, you are not taking into account that the target of $f$ is infinite dimensional, although of course, your matrix (or rather, its transpose), would be correct if you were considering $f$ as a map to its image (instead of the whole $\mathbb{R}[t]$).

Comment: Notwithstanding these minutiae, you're very close to the solution. Oh, apart from one coefficient in your matrix which is wrong (I just noticed)!

Comment: Ah, 4th column, 2nd row? should be 1... so would this matrix be defined as the image of f?

Comment: Correct. As for your question, well, "this matrix is defined as the image of $f$"  isn't a very precise statement. As I said, first you should consider the transpose (this is of course a matter of convention, but a convention well established which you should follow!), then what you can say is that the column vectors of the matrix span the image of $f$. The rest of your original answer is then standard basic linear algebra.

Comment: Ahh right! I see it, thanks. Any tips on finding ker(f)?

Comment: I believe you should be able to do that without my help (this should be explained in any respectable introductory exposition of linear algebra, and if it is not explained in the source you are following or in your course I suggest you look up some other source); besides we are already getting "Please avoid extended discussions in comments" messages... I will just give you a hint: once you've correctly put $f$ in matrix form, it is easy to see that the columns are not linearly independent.

Answer (score 1):

$$Ker(f)=\{\vec{v} \in \mathbb{R}^3 \mid f \vec{v}=0 \}$$
if you know what happens to a base it is easy to find the kernel. You can write any vector as a linear combination of vectors in the base, so, let $x,y,z$ be the coordinate of vector $\vec{v}$:

$$
f\vec{v}=0 
\iff f (x e_1 + y e_2 + z e_3)=0 
\iff xfe_1 + yfe_2 + zfe_3 = 0
$$

$$x(2t^2-t+1) + y(t^3-2t) + z(t^3-4t^2-2)=0$$
$$(y+z)t^3 + (2x-4)t^2 + (-x-2y)t + (x - 2z)=0$$

Now, $p(t) \in \mathbb{R}[t]$ is null iff each coefficient is zero, so:

$$
Ker(f) = 
\begin{cases}
    y+z=0\\
    2x-4z=0\\
    -x-2y=0\\
    x-2z=0
\end{cases}
$$

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
 0 & 1 &  1 \\
 2 & 0 & -4 \\
-1 & -2 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & -2 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\xrightarrow{ref}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & -2 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
A base of $Ker(f)$ is
$
\left\{
    \langle
    2, -1, 1 
    \rangle
\right\}$.

Now, the image of $f$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}[t]$. You have already the image of a base, and you knows that it spans $Img(f)$ (it is easy to demonstrate). We must check if the are independent polynomials, if so that means that they are also a base. We put their coefficients in a matrix and we show that [edit] indeed the third is dependent. So a base for the image is $\{f(e_1), f(e_2)\}$.

Comment: I am sure you are aware that the sum of the dimensions of the kernel and the image must be equal to the dimension of the source. This shows there is a little problem in your answer.

Comment: Sorry, the vectors in the image of the base are not independent, I will correct